# MySQL .execute TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, typeerror, execute

Can anyone help what is the problem with this code?

```
image_url = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, image_name)
cursor.execute("SELECT image_url FROM image_db WHERE image_url = %s",(image_url,))
```

I am getting this error>

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I tried formatting the string in different ways but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error. I can't reproduce the error from your `format()` call.

Comment: Make sure you really have a comma after `image_url` in the `cursor.execute()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your problem in my setup and didn't run into the error you mentioned. Maybe there's a difference in our setups or in the database. Here's the code I used for testing (with **Python version 3.11.5 and PyMySQL version 1.1.08**) :

```
bucket_name = 1
image_name = "mmap"
image_url = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, image_name)
conn = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.110.247', port=3306, user='root', 
password='root', database='matrixone')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = %s", (image_url,))
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
print(row)
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

And I didn't get any errors. It worked fine and gave me the correct results:

```
('gs://1/mmap',)
```

So, if you're still stuck, you might want to check if everything is set up correctly on your end, or if there's something different about how your database is expecting the data.